# strace a shebang script

Tags: linux, strace, shebang

I have a simple ruby script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Hello World"
```

When I run this using strace:

```
$ strace -s 100 -f ./script2
```

I get the following sequence of successful `execve` calls:

```
execve("./script2", ["./script2"], [/* 85 vars */]) = 0
execve("/home/omar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby", ["ruby", "./script2"], [/* 85 vars */]) = 0
```

these I was expecting to be present, but the output does not have any lines that execute the `/usr/bin/env` command. Why is this so? Does the `env` command get invoked by the `execve` system call internally? I want to know the sequence of events that ends with the `ruby` interpreter binary being execved.

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter specified in the shebang line is executed by the kernel itself inside the `execve` call.

Compare your script with a simple

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Hello World"
```

If you strace this script, you'll see only one `execve` call: the one with your script name as argument, not the Ruby interpreter.

Have a look at the `load_script` [kernel function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_script.c) for more details.